# I get "Module not found: Can't resolve './index.es2.js' " error when i try to consume my vite npm library with a Nextjs app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, vite, rollupjs

Here are the relevant files from my vite npm library:

```
//vite.config.ts
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import { resolve } from "path";
import { peerDependencies, dependencies } from "./package.json";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import dts from "vite-plugin-dts";

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react({
      jsxRuntime: "classic",
    }),
    dts({
      include: ["src/**/*"],
    }),
  ],
  build: {
    lib: {
      entry: resolve(__dirname, "src", "index.ts"),
      formats: ["es", "cjs"],
      fileName: (ext) => `index.${ext}.js`,
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      external: [
        ...Object.keys(peerDependencies),
        ...Object.keys(dependencies),
      ],
      output: { preserveModules: true, exports: "named" },
    },

    target: "esnext",
    sourcemap: true,
  },
});
```

```
//tsconfig.json

{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ESNext"],
    "allowJs": false,
    "skipLibCheck": false,
    "esModuleInterop": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsxdev",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
  },
  "include": ["./src"]
}
```

```
//package.json

{
  "name": "starter",
  "description": "A quick library starter for React with Tailwind CSS, Vite, TypeScript and Shadcn-ui components.",
  "private": false,
  "version": "0.0.21",
  "type": "module",
  "main": "dist/index.cjs.js",
  "module": "dist/index.es.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "sideEffects": false,
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/rajeshdavidbabu/shadcn-ui-lib-starter.git"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build && npm run build:styles",
    "build:styles": "postcss ./src/index.css -o ./dist/style.css",
    "lint": "eslint src --ext ts,tsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@radix-ui/react-avatar": "^1.0.3",
    "@radix-ui/react-slot": "^1.0.2",
    "class-variance-authority": "^0.6.0",
    "clsx": "^1.2.1",
    "lucide-react": "^0.221.0",
    "tailwind-merge": "^1.12.0",
    "tailwindcss-animate": "^1.0.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.0.28",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.57.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.57.1",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
    "eslint": "^8.38.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.3.4",
    "postcss": "^8.4.23",
    "postcss-cli": "^10.1.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.2",
    "typescript": "^5.0.2",
    "vite": "^4.3.2",
    "vite-plugin-dts": "^2.3.0"
  }
}
```

When i run npm run build, my /dist looks like this, notice all of the cjs2, cjs3, cjs4... :
[image]

Everything works fine if i consume this app in a CSR app.

But when i try to consume this library in a Nextjs app I get

`X ./node_modules/starter/dist/index.es.js:1:0 Module not found: Can't resolve './index.es2.js'`

I think it has to do with how my vite.config.js is setup. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: can you also share a minimal reproducible repo?